# laravel many-to-many relationship return non related data

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relational-database

I have a relationship in my applications that is basically,

> Many Organisations can have many Users, and many Users can have many Organisations.

So a many-to-many relationship, the organisation model relationship looks like this,

```
public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')
                    ->where('admin', '>', 0)
                    ->orWhere('basic', '>', 0)
                    ->withPivot([
                        'start_date'       =>    'start_date as start_date',
                        'admin'            =>    'admin as admin',
                        'manager'          =>    'manager as manager',
                        'finance'          =>    'finance as finance',
                        'basic'            =>    'basic as basic',
                        'notifications'    =>    'notifications as notify'
                    ])
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and my user model relationship to organisations looks like this,

```
public function organisations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation');
}
```

I am having a huge problem with this relationship however, when I access this through project ( a project has one organisation, that has many users), I get a full list of users rather than just the users of the organisation for that project.

Why would this be? I think it is to do with my where clauses in the Users() function in my organisation model?

Comment: Why isn't the relationship like so "Many Organisations can have many Users, and many Users belong to many Organisations."? Then the models will have `public function users() { return $this->hasMany('\App\User') ...` and `public function organisations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Organisation');
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason you use all this code! I would say, Just make it simple:

**Organisation class**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**User class**

```
public function organisations() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Organisation');
}
```